# Take input value from submit form and store in redux store to use later

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-hooks

I'm doing a project where the first screen is a simple input to put the name on, and then it goes to another screen (another component) where I need to use the value that the user put in the input earlier to show custom content. I tried to do it with Redux but I'm having difficulties to store the input value in the Redux Store and then use that value in another component. I would like to know how I could store this value and then use it in another component (I honestly have no idea how to do it).  If anyone wants, I can also show the other component code.

my first component (where user puts his name):

```js
import React, {useState, useEffect} from "react";
import "../_assets/signup.css";
import "../_assets/App.css";
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
    
function Signup() {
  const [name, setName] = useState('')
  const [buttonGrey, setButtonGrey] = useState('#cccccc')
    
  useEffect(() => {
    if(name!== '') {
      setButtonGrey("black")
    } else {
      setButtonGrey('#cccccc')
    }
  }, [name])
    
  const handleSubmitForm= (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    store.dispatch({
      type: 'SAVE_USER',
      payload: name,
    })
    console.log({name})
  }
    
  const handleChangeName = (text) => {
    setName(text)
  }
    
  return (
    <div className="container">
      <div className="LoginBox">
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmitForm}>
          <h2>Welcome to codeleap network</h2>
          <text>Please enter your username</text>
          <input
            type="text" 
            name="name" 
            value={name} 
            onChange = {e => handleChangeName(e.target.value)} 
            placeholder="Jane Doe" 
          />
          <div className="button">
            <Link to="/main">
              <button 
                type="submit" 
                style={{backgroundColor: buttonGrey}} 
                disabled={!name} 
              >
                ENTER
              </button>
            </Link>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
    
export default Signup;
```

my store.js:

```js
import { createStore } from 'redux';
        
const reducer = (state= (''), action) => {
  switch(action.type) {
    case 'SAVE_USER': {
      state = {...state, name: action.payload}
    }
    default: return state
  }
}
        
const store = createStore(reducer)
            
export {store}
```

## Heading

[image]

Comment: This code isn't using Redux at all. Are you asking how to get started with using Redux to persist state? https://redux-toolkit.js.org/ What have you tried already on your own?

Comment: Yes, I read a lot about Redux but I confess that I didn't understand enough to accomplish what I need, so I wanted to know "where to start".  (I edit and added the store code).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I suggest using [Redux-Toolkit](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/). It makes standing up and configuring a React redux store almost too easy.

Here's the [quick-start guide](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/tutorials/quick-start)

1. Create/convert to a state slice. When you create a slice you are declaring the name of the slice of state, the actions, *and* the reducer functions at the same time all at once.

   ```
   import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

   const userSlice = createSlice({
     name: "user",
     initialState: "",
     reducers: {
       saveUser: (state, action) => action.payload
     }
   });
   ```
2. Create and configure the store.

   ```
   import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
   import userSlice from "../path/to/userSlice";

   const store = configureStore({
     reducer: {
       user: userSlice.reducer
     }
   });
   ```
3. Render a `Provider` and pass the `store` prop.

   ```
   import { Provider } from "react-redux";

   <Provider store={store}>
     ... app component ...
   </Provider>
   ```

From here it's a matter of importing the `dispatch` function and selecting state, use `useDispatch` and `useSelector` from `react-redux` for this.

Signup

```
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";

function Signup() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch(); // <-- dispatch function
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const [name, setName] = useState("");

  const handleSubmitForm = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    dispatch(userSlice.actions.saveUser(name)); // <-- dispatch the action
    navigate("/main");
  };

  const handleChangeName = (text) => {
    setName(text);
  };

  return (
    ...
  );
}
```

Example Main component:

```
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";

const Main = () => {
  const user = useSelector((state) => state.user); // <-- select the user state

  return (
    <>
      <h1>Main</h1>
      <div>User: {user}</div>
    </>
  );
};
```

[image: Edit take-input-value-from-submit-form-and-store-in-redux-store-to-use-later]

Comment: Thank you bro!!! you helped me a lot!! I tested it here and got the result I was looking for... Thank you for real

Comment: One more question: the other component of my application is a CRUD, where the user can create a post, edit it and so on. I need the posts he creates are not deleted when he goes back to the previous page (input page). I tried to do a process similar to what you taught me to save posts but it didn't work, is there any tips to do this? I'll leave a print to show how this component is.

Comment: @HeitorKenzou This sounds like a *different* issue (*a bit off-topic*) than what you asked about in this post. If you post a new question you can get more eyes on the new issue more quickly. Feel free to ping me here with a link to it if you like and I can take a look when I've time.